# monitor keep flickering-python and ultrasonic sensor

Tags: python, sensors, monitor

the sensor i use is HC-SR04.
i use it to turn the monitor in to sleep mode when it sense object more that 30cm.
it turns on when sense object less or equal 30 cm.
it work fine when turn into sleep mode,but like flickering when it turns ON.Please help me~~~
below is my coding

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import subprocess
import sys
# Use BCM GPIO references
# instead of physical pin numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False) 
# Define GPIO to use on Pi
GPIO_TRIGGER = 23
GPIO_ECHO = 24

print "Ultrasonic Measurement"
while True:
        # Set pins as output and input
        GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER,GPIO.OUT)  # Trigger
        GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO,GPIO.IN)      # Echo

        # Set trigger to False (Low)
        GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)

        # Allow module to settle
        time.sleep(2)

        # Send 10us pulse to trigger
        GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)
        time.sleep(0.00001)
        GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
        start = time.time()
        while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==0:
          start = time.time()

        while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==1:
          stop = time.time()

        # Calculate pulse length
        elapsed = stop-start

        # Distance pulse travelled in that time is time
        # multiplied by the speed of sound (cm/s)
        distance = elapsed * 34000

        # That was the distance there and back so halve the value
        distance = distance / 2

        print "Distance : %.1f" % distance
        if(distance > 30):
            time.sleep(3)
            subprocess.call("sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o",shell=True)


            os.system('clear')
        if(distance <= 30):
                subprocess.call("sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -p",shell=True)


# Reset GPIO settings
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error or noise in your measurement causing it to fluctuate. This could be partially due to trying to measure it using the Python GPIO module which may be a bit slow. There are two things you could try:

1. Add some [hysteresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis) to your trigger points

   ```
   if(distance > 40): # switch off if distance is greater than 40
       time.sleep(3)
       subprocess.call("sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o",shell=True)

       os.system('clear')
   if(distance <= 30): # switch on if distance is less than 30
           subprocess.call("sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -p",shell=True)
   ```
2. Add some filtering to your readings. You could use a [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) filter say

   ```
   previous_readings = []
   while 1:
       previous_readings.append(new_reading)
       previous_readings = previous_readings[-10:] # just keep the last 10 readings
       avg_reading = sum(previous_readings) / len(previous_readings)
   ```

Alternatively, measuring the time more accurately with a microcontroller might help.

You should probably also keep track of whether the screen is already on or off and only switch it as needed

```
screen_on = False
...
while 1:
...
    if (screen_on and distance > 40): # switch off if distance is greater than 40
        time.sleep(3)
        subprocess.call("sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o",shell=True)
        screen_on = False

        os.system('clear')
    if (not screen_on and distance <= 30): # switch on if distance is less than 30
        subprocess.call("sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -p",shell=True)
        screen_on = True
```

Comment: how to set screen off in initial state?